# What's a good toolchain and deployment process for GIT and Deployment for a Windows user working on a LAMP Stack?

Tags: php, linux, git, deployment, web-development-server

I run a custom PHP site on a Managed VPS (LAMP stack) and am the solo developer, but want to start using GIT so freelancers can contribute. Currently I don't use GIT.

**GIT**

For GIT, I wanted to use Visual Studio Online (VSO) since I've used it before but am open to suggestions if it's better for the suggested deployment process.

**Deployment**

I kept a "Dev" folder and a "Live" folder on the web server and simply did all of my dev in the Dev folder, tested there, then ran **rsync** to push it to the Live folder. I couldn't easily run it locally since it has things like Linux symlinks, and I work on a Windows computer.

**The Goal**

I want to start adding GIT to this process, integrate that into a decent build process, and still use a Windows IDE for development. Though maybe I should install a Linux VM on my Windows machine so I can start running the site directly from pulling the latest version from GIT?

I need a setup that would be easy for other developers to join on as I find freelancers to help out.

Suggestions?

Comment: If you're using git don't use rsync to deploy to live, use *git*. Leverage branches, pull requests, etc. Give this a read, there's a section later on that details a few common git workflows. https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/syncing

Comment: That said, your question is far too broad and opinion-based for StackOverflow. Once you read up on the issue I'm sure there's another site on StackExchange that can handle broader questions, but unless you've got a specific, technical issue with git it's not likely well-suited for SO.

Answer (score 0):

here's what I do for

### Git deployment

For deployment, I follow a very-simple git-flow technique (http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/#the-main-branches) with 2 branches:

- `master` for prod
- `dev` for new features

You always develop new features on `dev` branch, so `dev` is always ahead of master in term of functionnalities.

When you want to deploy, you SSH on your server, you `git pull dev` branch, and if everything works fine, you `git merge` with master.

You can always switch on the prod server between prod and dev version with `git branch master` and `git branch dev`. No need of 2 folders, git handles this !

If you have a bug on prod environment, you can switch branch to master on your local computer and fix the bug. Then you upload it via ssh.

### Multi collaborator development (developers with windows/linux/mac but 1 production server)

I personally use docker, it creates a single VM which you can customize to match your prod environment (linux version, apache version, php version and my sql version). You create 1 docker image, and then every collaborator can download this image and run it on his computer.